# Turning a list of strings into float

Tags: python, string, list

I printed some data from an external file and split the data into a string:

```
string = data
splitstring = string.split(',')
print(splitstring)
```

which gave me:

```
['500', '500', '0.5', '50', '1.0', '0.75', '0.50', '0.25', '0.00']
```

I tried to turn them into floats using this method:

```
for c in splitstring:
    splitstring[c]=float(splitstring[c])
```

But it gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/katiemoore/Documents/MooreKatie_assign10_attempt2.py", line 44, in <module>
    splitstring[c]=float(splitstring[c])
 TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a list comprehension:

```
splitstring = [float(s) for s in splitstring]
```

or, on Python 2, for speed, use `map()`:

```
splitstring = map(float, splitstring)
```

When you loop over a list in Python, you don't get indexes, you get the *values themselves*, so `c` is not an integer but a string value (`'500'` in the first iteration).

You'd have to use `enumerate()` to generate indices for you, together with the actual values:

```
for i, value in enumerate(splitstring):
    splitstring[i] = float(value)
```

or use `for c in range(len(splitstring)):` to *only* produce indices. But the list comprehension and `map()` options are better anyway.